# Combining two files by inserting even lines of one file after even lines of other file

Tags: file, awk, sed, concatenation

I would like to know a way to combine two files efficiently. I wanted to concatenate only even lines of `FileB` after even lines of `FileA`. I think it can be done easily with sed or awk. Any help is appreciated.

FileA:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
.
.
```

FileB:

```
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
B6
.
.
```

Output:

```
A1
A2
B2
A3
A4
B4
A5
.
```

Comment: Does your output has a particular pattern ? What have you tried ?

Comment: What happens if A or B run out of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that avoids storing one of the files in memory:

```
awk -v f=FileB '{print} NR%2==0 {getline<f; getline<f; print}' FileA
```

#### How it works:

- `-v f=FileB`

  This creates an awk variable `f` which contains the name of FileB.
- `{print}`

  This prints every line read from FileA.
- `NR%2==0 {getline<f; getline<f; print}`

  If we are on an even line, meaning `NR%2==0`, then we read two lines from FileB and print the second one.

#### Sample output:

```
$ awk -v f=FileB '{print} NR%2 == 0{getline<f; getline <f; print}' FileA
A1
A2
B2
A3
A4
B4
A5
A6
B6
```

#### More cryptic version

Awk allows prints to be performed with cryptic shorthand notations:

```
awk -v f=FileB '1; NR%2{next} {getline<f; getline <f} 1' FileA
```

Here, `1` is a *condition* which evaluates to true.  Since no *action* is specified, the default action is performed which is to print the line.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'NR==FNR {b[NR]=$0; next} 1; !(FNR%2){print b[FNR]}' fileB fileA
```

if files are large, you can cut the array size by only storing the printed lines of fileB.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `paste`, sed and process substitution:

```
$ paste -d '\n' <(sed '2~2d' fileA) <(sed '1~2d' fileA) <(sed '1~2d' fileB)
A1
A2
B2
A3
A4
B4
A5
A6
B6
```

Explained:

- `paste -d '\n'` pastes the files line by line, delimited by newlines, effectively interleaving them
- `sed '2~2d' fileA` prints the odd lines of `fileA` (by deleting the even lines)
- `sed '1~2d' fileA` prints the even lines of `fileA`
- `sed '1~2d' fileB` prints the even lines of `fileB`

Comment: Awesome solution Benjamin

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed '1~2d' fileB | sed '2~2R /dev/stdin' fileA
```

Filter fileB on even numbered lines and pass the resulting file via a pipe to a second invocation of sed that appends these lines to only the even numbered lines in fileA.