# using sed or awk to insert line between two files

Tags: bash, sed

I have two files, file A and file B:

Inside fileA.txt:

```
lineA
lineB
lineC
lineD
lineE
```

and inside fileB.txt:

```
object1
object2
```

expected outcome:

```
lineA
lineB
object1
lineC
lineD
object2
lineE
```

i am quite lost for overlapping two files, it is a small files, so it does not have to be very automaticlly. I am try to do something like this:

```
cat fileA.txt | sed -n 1p >> fileB.txt | 3p?
cat fileA.txt | sed -n 2p >> fileB.txt | 6p?
```

please help

Comment: What is your rule ? Every two lines in A insert one line of B ?

Comment: there is no rules, maybe add line 1 from file a to the line 5 of file b

Comment: Let me rephrase : how do we know where to put line from fileB in fileA ?

Comment: Extremely similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43859055/3266847

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining two files by inserting even lines of one file after even lines of other file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859055/combining-two-files-by-inserting-even-lines-of-one-file-after-even-lines-of-othe)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this `GNU sed`, if every two lines in file A insert one line of file B.

```
sed 'n;R file2' file1
```

**Output:**

```
$ sed 'n;R file2' file1
lineA
lineB
object1
lineC
lineD
object2
lineE
```

From `man sed`:

> R filename
>
> Append a line read from filename.  Each invocation of the command reads a line from the file.  This is a **GNU** extension.

Comment: @Inian, This is a `GNU sed`. Updated in my answer.

Comment: what tells sed to pick two lines in fileA then one line in fileB, and so on ?

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. If you are using sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using the wrong tool. For any other text manipulation problems you should be using awk for clarity, simplicity, portability, efficiency, and most other desirable attributes of software:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print} FNR%2==0{print a[++c]}' fileB fileA
lineA
lineB
object1
lineC
lineD
object2
lineE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '0~2 R file_name_2'  file_name_1
```

> 0~2 -  after every second line
>
> R filename - Append a line read from filename. Each invocation of the
>   command reads a line from the file.

Comment: You need to add some explanation of the answer and why it works. Otherwise it is likely to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[FNR]=$0;next} {printf("%s%s\n",$0,FNR%2==0?ORS A[++i]:"")}' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

Checking FNR==NR condition which will be TRUE when file fileB.txt will be read. It is creating array named A whose index is line number and it's value is current line of fileB.txt's lines. next will be skip all further statements when file named fileB.txt is being read.
printing the current line of fileA.txt and checking condition if FNR%2==0 then print the array A's values with increasing values of variable I.

```
lineA
lineB
object1
lineC
lineD
object2
lineE
```

Comment: IMHO, getline is a better approach than FNR==NR for this problem because it does not need to load an entire file.

Comment: `print $0 (FNR%2 ? "" : ORS A[++i])` instead of `printf("%s%s\n",$0,FNR%2==0?ORS A[++i]:"")` would IMHO be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Another in awk, using mod (`%`) and `getline`:

```
awk '1;NR%2==0{if((getline line < "fileB")>0)print line}' fileA
lineA
lineB
object1
lineC
lineD
object2
lineE
```

After every other line in `fileA` print a line from `fileB` if there are any left.

Comment: IMHO, getline is a better approach than FNR==NR for this problem because it does not need to load an entire file.

Comment: @Setop the OP specifically said `it is a small files` so why open yourself up to the complexity, caveats, and difficulty of adding functionality to a getline solution (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline)? For example, imagine you realize you do not want to print lines starting with `#` from either file - with a getline solution you need to add that test in 2 separate places since you read each file in different ways, but with a non-getline solution you just need `/^#/{next}` at the start. What if you just want to print the total lines at the end (`END{print NR}` won't work)? etc....

Comment: @EdMorton Nice example in general that `/^#/{next}` but in this particular question if `#` was added in front of, for example, `lineB` of `fileA`, it would cause that `object1` of `fileB` would be skipped - or moved to the next position - as well.

Comment: In the example I was trying to give, any line from either file that starts with `#` **should** be skipped. Yes, something would have to be done with FNR too but the point I was trying to get across (maybe poorly) is that when you have 2 completely different ways to read your input files then it becomes difficult to write code that's common to the processing of both input files.

Comment: @EdMorton that's my point : to me "getline" is less complex than the "FNR==NR" trick.The "what if I want this and that" does not help. I can find  "what if"s that are in favor of "getline" : what if my input does not come from a file but a subprocess.

Comment: Having to perform actions only for select lines is an extremely common requirement (the one awk was primarily designed to handle) while taking input from a subprocess would be a totally different type of problem than the one the OP is dealing with. `getline` just **appears** to be less complex than other approaches and because it lets you write awk code like you would have to write C or shell or other procedural code that they may be used to people get sucked in by it but it is rarely the right approach, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: @EdMorton Where processing 2 (or more) files at once is complex, I love the idea that it can be done with `getline` and with so little effort. <3 I also know that it can come back and bite me, though. I'd like to think that above usage is safe?

Comment: @JamesBrown yes, the way you used getline is safe. The only problem with it is it's not easily extensible if/when requirements change and "fileB" is hard-coded which probably isn't ideal.